# The difference between a plugin and an application plugin in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

There is a quite similar question here: [What's the difference between a twistd plugin and a twistd service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6720021/248296)

And the answer is:

> A plugin is nicer in that you can have command-line options

When i started learning twisted i was working with an existing application, and i was confused where is the entry point, which was somewhere in `twisted/plugins` folder.

From then my preferred way is using `tac` files in the top folder, but now i got to a point when i need to pass some command line arguments to my script. And i am told to use twisted application plugins.

I am confused by the term `plugin` in twisted. For me it means somethings that changes an application in a seamless way - you don't really have to know they exist - they just 'plug in' into your application changing its behavior.

But i cannot understand the conceptual difference between twisted applications and twisted application plugins. For me - they serve the same purpose, but are given different features - why?

When should i use twisted applications and when plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins in twisted only adds commands and/or options to `twistd` script. They don't mean anything more.

So well yes, there are two ways to write a startup script for your application, one is using `.tac` file and one is to add a command (through plugin) to `twistd`.

I think `.tac` file is easier to write.

I think it is not a wrong thing to use both: plugins and `.tac` files.

There is also a third way: write your own startup script instead of `twistd`.

> But i cannot understand the conceptual difference between twisted
>   applications and twisted application plugins. For me - they serve the
>   same purpose, but are given different features - why?

Well no. They don't serve same purpose. Twisted application is just a `.tac` file that can be started with `twistd` script. It is more like a config file. Config file with python syntax. It's purpose is that you don't need to write your own start-up script. But if `twistd` does not provide enough options for you, you can write a plugin for it. So the purpose for plugins is to extend `twistd`.

And if I had to publish a stand alone application I would write my own startup script and would not use `twistd` script. `twistd` is ok if users of the application are familiar with twisted and or has more twisted apps. I think it is only a burden to user to see all the different options of `twistd` and it is very frustrating not to be able to start application without referring to documentation.

For example [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) does that: it provides a script `scrapyd` for users who are not familiar with twisted.

Comment: >And if I had to publish a stand alone application I would write my own startup script and would not use twistd script. >For example scrapy does that: it provides a script scrapyd for users who are not familiar with twisted. < scrapyd source: `twistd -ny "$tacfile"`